# react-testing-library - async behaviors are sometimes passing, sometimes failing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm writing tests for my react-app using `react-testing-library` and I've come across an issue I can't quite figure out.

In my use-case, a user needs to enter a value into an input and then click the search button. **If the input is valid, we fire an async function to go and retrieve the data from my api.** If the input data is valid and the data "comes back", then we **enable** the two subsequent `<select>` inputs and the user can continue working through the form.

*So in a nutshell:*

1. user adds a video address in the first input
2. `onClick` triggers search event. if it's valid, fetch the data from the endpoint
3. once data returns, remove the disabled feature from the two following select inputs

---

Pretty cut and dry. However, I'm experiencing some strange behaviors that I can't quite figure out.

- both `<select>` inputs share the same logic for being enabled/disabled, **yet in my test results *one or both* return as disabled and fail the test run.**
- if I add a `screen.debug()` invocation following either of those failing assertions, **(SOMETIMES) all tests pass** and in those cases the `screen.debug()` console response matches what I'm expecting to see.

So, the tests are all over the place. It smells like things *can* work as expected, but there is some sort of asynchronous race condition that I'm having trouble resolving. At least, that's the impression I'm getting. I'd appreciate some help getting to the bottom of this.

##### react-testing-library tests

```js
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from "../../../testing-utils/test-utils";
import { rest } from "msw";
import { setupServer } from "msw/node";

const youtubeGetEndpoint = getApiAddress(ApiEndpointsEnum.youtubeId, [
  `0La3aBSjvGY`,
]);

const server = setupServer(
  rest.get(youtubeGetEndpoint, (req, res, ctx) => {
    return res(ctx.json({ greeting: "hello there" }));
  })
);

beforeAll(() => server.listen());
afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers());
afterAll(() => server.close());

  describe("when a user inputs a url for a youtube video", () => {
    describe("if the url is valid", () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
        // trigger async behavior beforeEach
        render(<SelectMedia />);
        user.type(
          screen.getByTestId(/input-source-url/i),
          "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0La3aBSjvGY"
        );
        user.click(screen.getByRole("button", { name: /search/i }));
      });

      test("the VideoPlayer activates with the provided content", async () => {
      // seems to consistently pass
        expect(
          await screen.findByTestId(/video-player-enabled/i)
        ).toBeInTheDocument();
      });

      test("the sourceLanguage input is no longer disabled", async () => {
      // sometimes passes/sometimes fails
        expect(
          await screen.findByTestId(/input-select-source-language/i)
        ).toBeEnabled();
      });

      test("the targetLanguage input is no longer disabled", async () => {
      // sometimes passes/sometimes fails
        expect(
          await screen.findByTestId(/input-select-target-language/i)
        ).toBeEnabled();
        screen.debug();
      });
   })
})
```

#### component's search function

```js
  const onSearch = async () => {
    const values = getValues();
    const youtubeId = youtubeGetId(values.sourceURL);

    if (youtubeId.length === 11) {
      const response = await searchYoutubeVideo(youtubeId);
      console.log("data", response); 
      // console.log returns with { greeting: "hello there" }, which is good.
      if (mountedRef.current) {
        setShowVideo(true);
        // setting this to `true` _should_ enable the inputs
        dispatch(
          setAlert({
            type: "success",
            message: "Video found.",
            display: "support-both",
          })
        );
      }
    } else {
      setShowVideo(false);
      dispatch(
        setAlert({
          type: "warning",
          message: "Invalid address provided.",
          display: "support-both",
        })
      );
    }
  };
```

##### component's form

```js
const [showVideo, setShowVideo] = useState(false);
// ^ the only component state that's relevant for this example
...
return (
<>
  <div>
    <VideoPlayerController
      playable={showVideo}
      withDetails={false}
      embedURL=""
      timeStamp={{ startTime: 0, endTime: 10 }}
    />
  <button onClick={onSearch}>Search</button>
  // ^ the onSearch() shown above
  </div>
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
    <FormControlInputs>
      <Controller
        name="sourceURL"
        control={control}
        defaultValue=""
        rules={{ required: true }}
        render={({ field }) => (
          <TextField
            fullWidth
            label="Youtube Address"
            inputProps={{
              "data-testid": "input-source-url",
            }}
            variant="filled"
            disabled={false}
            placeholder="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0La3aBSjvGY"
            error={!!errors.sourceURL}
            helperText={
              errors.sourceURL
                ? "A valid youtube address is required"
                : "Enter the address of a youtube video"
            }
            {...field}
          />
        )}
      />

      <SelectInputWrapper>
        <Typography variant="overline">Language Mapping</Typography>
        <SelectWrapper>
          <Controller
            name="sourceLanguage"
            rules={{ required: "this field is required" }}
            control={control}
            defaultValue=""
            render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
              <TextField
                select
                fullWidth
                label="Source Language"
                variant="filled"
                value={value}
                disabled={showVideo ? false : true}
                {* this is the disabled feature we're looking at *}
                error={!!errors.sourceLanguage}
                onChange={onChange}
                inputProps={{
                  "data-testid": "input-select-source-language",
                }}
                helperText={
                  errors.sourceLanguage
                    ? "Please select the language used in the provided media"
                    : "Select the language used in the provided media"
                }
              >
                <MenuItem value="">None</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value="en-US">English</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value="fr-FR">French</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value="es-ES">Spanish</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value="de-DE">German</MenuItem>
              </TextField>
            )}
          />
        </SelectWrapper>
      </SelectInputWrapper>
      <SelectInputWrapper>
        <Typography variant="overline">Language Mapping</Typography>
        <SelectWrapper>
          <Controller
            name="targetLanguage"
            rules={{ required: "this field is required" }}
            control={control}
            defaultValue=""
            render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
              <TextField
                select
                fullWidth
                label="Target Language"
                variant="filled"
                value={value}
                disabled={showVideo ? false : true}
                {* this is the disabled feature we're looking at *}
                error={!!errors.targetLanguage}
                onChange={onChange}
                inputProps={{
                  "data-testid": "input-select-target-language",
                }}
                helperText={
                  errors.targetLanguage
                    ? "Please select a language to translate the media into"
                    : "Select a language to translate the content into"
                }
              >
                <MenuItem value="">None</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value="en">English</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value="fr">French</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value="es">Spanish</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value="de">German</MenuItem>
              </TextField>
            )}
          />
        </SelectWrapper>
      </SelectInputWrapper>
      <LoadingButton
        endIcon={<SendIcon />}
        loading={contentSubmitted}
        disabled={submitDisabled}
        loadingPosition="end"
        variant="contained"
        type="submit"
      >
        {contentSubmitted ? "building lesson" : "build lesson"}
      </LoadingButton>
    </FormControlInputs>
  </form>
</>
);
```

Comment: I think you should use `waitFor()` to keep checking until the condition is passed.

Comment: The documentation makes it seem like `findBy` and `waitFor` are pretty much the same thing. Is that not the case?

Comment: No, findBy waits until it can find an element in the dom. WaitFor keeps running the callback multiple times, until the conditions inside passes, or until timeout.

Comment: interesting, thank you. It passes with `waitFor`